# How to debug electron main process with renderer process with Angular

Tags: node.js, angular, debugging, visual-studio-code, electron

I am developing an electron application which uses angular. I can debug the angular code by using the `BrowserWindow.webContents.openDevTools()`. I also can debug the main process of electron in VS Code using the `launch.json` with below config.

```
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Debug Main Process",
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
      "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron",
      "windows": {
        "runtimeExecutable": "${workspaceFolder}/node_modules/.bin/electron.cmd"
      },
      "args" : ["."],
      "outputCapture": "std"
    }
  ]
}
```

My question is how to debug both of these together as the complete flow.

I uses `npm start` to run the application which runs the command `npm run postinstall:electron && npm-run-all -p ng:serve electron:serve`

I tried to put many solutions together to achieve this but I still couldn't find a solutions. If anyone has any idea, it will be much appreciated. Thanks.